# what's the difference between "vector<int>& a " and "vector<int> a"?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector

I'm the beginner in C++. I try to write a program to rotate a vector one by one

i.e., {1,2,3,4,5} --> {2,3,4,5,1} --> {3,4,5,1,2}

```
vector<vector<int>> allrot(const vector<int>& a)
{  
   vector<vector<int>> result;
   for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i ++ ){
      rotate(a.begin(), a.begin() + 1, a.end());
      result.push_back(a);
   }
   return result;
}
```

This doesn't work, and I have several questions.

1. Why should I use `vector<int>& a` rather than `vector<int> a` ?
2. What's wrong with my code ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I would suggest you to buy a good book /  read something on the documentation

Comment: You are getting an error because you are trying to call `rotate` on a `const` vector. You can work around this and keep the parameter `const` by first adding then rotating. `result.push_back(a); rotate(result.back().begin(), result.back().begin() + i + 1, result.back().end());`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You could also use `rotate_copy` there, and I think it should be faster? You would: `result.emplace_back(std::vector<int>(a.size()); std::rotate_copy(a.begin(), a.begin() + i + 1, a.end(), result.back().begin());`

Answer (score 4):

When you pass `vector<int>` then function gets a copy of that vector. You can do anything you want with it in the function and your original data would not change.

When you pass `vector<int>&` then function gets the reference which means that any changes in the function would modify the original data.